# Do Amazon Workspaces support Docker for Windows?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-workspaces

I'm currently using a VM hosted on-site by the company I work for. The VM is pretty slow, and we're looking at doing something about it. The choices are to get people off of VMs and onto physical hardware, upgrade our VM host or potentially move to Amazon Workspaces.

One of the challenges we're hitting on our current host is that we're running into problems having nested virtualization to run Docker on our workspaces.

Obviously, if we were to move to physical hardware, we would not have the problem with nested virtualization. If we upgrade our current hardware to be faster/better, we may not solve the underlying issue with nested virtualization.

It would be ideal if Amazon Workspaces supported Windows 10 with Docker for Windows allowing nested virtualization.

Does anybody on here use AWS workspaces with Windows? Do you use Docker?
Any other alternatives(other than AWS workspaces) that can be used to run Docker on Windows VM?

Comment: We have the same problem

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this is now documented in the Amazon [WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-troubleshooting.html#docker_support) troubleshooting guide.  As of Jan, 2021 Docker is now supported on Linux but not supported on Windows.

> Nested virtualization (including the use of Docker) is not supported on Windows WorkSpaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still interested, but we hit the same issue. The Windows image for WorkSpaces is still Windows Server 2016, which does support Docker but only Windows containers unless you're willing to install an out-of-date project to convert. WS 2019 does support it, so whenever Amazon upgrades their images, Docker will be supported on Windows.

For now, we just use Amazon Linux 2 and Docker works.

Comment: now we are in 2023 , does the AWS Workspaces support Docker on Windows ??